# При загрузке jpeg файла Post File запросом на сервере создаётся файл с данными из заголовка запроса

Tags: c#, файлы, post

Пишу программу на C#, которая автоматически заливает файлы документов формата .pdf .jpg на сторонний веб сервис. Написал следующую типовую процедуру для заливки файла на веб сервис, в неё передаётся строка Content-Disposition 
Вида

> "attachment; UserID=""; FileName="Image.jpg"; UserPacketID=""; LastFile="true"; UserAgent="UserAgent"; WithoutRecognition="false""

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Асинхронно выполняет Post запрос для загрузки файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="URL">Ссылка для выполнения Post запроса</param>
    /// <param name="FileStream">Поток для добавления данных в тело запроса</param>
    /// <param name="FileName">Имя файла</param>
    /// <returns>Текстовая строка XML ответ сервера</returns>
    private async Task<string> PostFileRequest(string URL, byte[] FileByteArray, string FileName, string ContentDisposition)
    {
        try
        {
            string responseString = "";  

            HttpContent BinaryData = new ByteArrayContent(FileByteArray);         

            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(ContentDisposition, out ContentDispositionHeaderValue ContentDispositionObject);

                formData.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionObject;

                formData.Add(BinaryData, "BinaryData");

                var response = await this.MainClient.PostAsync(URL, formData);
                responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            if (this.OnException != null)
            {
                OnException(this, new BetterHttpClientExceptionArgs("\nПроизошла ошибка при выполнении Post File запроса\n" + Exc.Source + "\n" + Exc.Message, this.LastResponse));
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

При этом файлы на сервер загружаются без ошибок, в ответе приходит идентификатор файла, но потом выясняется, что на сервер файл записался вместе с частью заголовков Post File запроса в двоичном виде в начале файла (первые 90 байтов), подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобным, в каком направлении копать?
(Проблема возникает почему-то только с jpg файлами, а pdf файлы нормально записываются) 
Заранее спасибо!

Используется стандартный HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть WebClient  который имеет метод Upload который загружает файлы

что то типа такова

Если надо то есть авторизация

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string myFile = @"D:\test_file.txt";
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    client.UploadFile(@"http://localhost/uploads/upload.php", "POST", myFile);
    client.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

Думаю это должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую реализовать загрузку через вебклиент.